# Using postgres_fdw to connect from one read replica to another

Tags: postgresql, replication, read-only-database

I have two postgres database servers in AWS, A and B. These databases have different tables. Both databases also have their own read replica.

**My goal is a simple solution for doing cross database joins from A replica to B replica. Querying from master is not an option, as this feature is meant for the analyst on my team, not for an application.**

I set up postgres_fdw on A's master following the [instructions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html) by doing CREATE SERVER, CREATE USER MAPPING, and CREATE FOREIGN TABLEs, and I was able to easily query from A master to B replica. However, these server and foreign table definitions did NOT replicate to A replica. I am unable to run these create commands on the replica as it is read-only.

Is it possible to use postgres_fdw from A replica to B replica? If not, is there another solution for this problem?

Comment: If you set up the foreign server etc. on A master, they **will** replicate to A replica.   You are doing something wrong.  Without seeing the error message you got, it is hard to say what that is.

Comment: Okay....so the foreign tables are on the replica under the user whose mapping I defined. But when I try to SELECT on them, the query hangs and times out eventually with `[08001] ERROR: could not connect to server "api"`.

Comment: Maybe a firewall issue?  Can you run psql on the same machine as A replica is running, and connect to B replica manually using the same hostname, port, username, and password given in the server and user mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create replicas using logical decoding.
Check pglogical https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical

When creating replica using logical decoding it's not read-only.Might help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach here would be creating extension, server, user mapping and foreign tables on master.

Then query all those on any slave...

Comment: In my question I stated: "However, these server and foreign table definitions did NOT replicate to A replica"

Comment: Oh. I thought you have streaming replication